# Run all 'add-apt-repository' commands first, then run a single 'apt-get update'

Tags: ubuntu, debian, puppet

I'm writing Puppet manifests for installing a lot of software on my machines.

Many software packages only feature the latest versions of the binary in PPAs, such as a really handly service called [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey).

To install this latest version of the package, one must do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:cdekter/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

Many other packages exist in this distribution format; one must install the PPA repository, then update APT, then install it.

Unfortunately, `apt-get update` takes quite a while  to run, and while installing tens of packages like this one, I could save quite a lot of time in provisioning if I only ran `apt-get update` after all PPA repositories were added.

Is there a way to do this in a straightforward manner in Puppet?

Answer (score 2):

[Puppetlabs' apt module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt) does exactly what you want.

Simply add your repo like this:

```
apt::ppa { 'ppa:cdekter/ppa ': }
```

If the repository was not added before this will automatically add the cdekter ppa and execute `apt-get update`. If it was already added nothing will happen.

### How it works

At the top of the `ppa.pp` manifest in Puppetlabs' apt module `apt::update` is included:

```
include apt::update
```

The `update.pp` manifest revolves around this exec:

```
  exec { 'apt_update':
    command     => "${apt::params::provider} update",
    logoutput   => 'on_failure',
    refreshonly => true,
    timeout     => $apt::update_timeout,
  }
```

This `exec` is defined as `refreshonly => true`, meaning it will not be executed unless it is triggered by [a refresh event](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#refreshing). Refresh events are basically signals between resources that something has changed and can be set by the notify and subscribe metaparameters. Thus when you simply `include apt::update` this exec will not fire unless some other resource sent it a refresh event.

The `ppa.pp` manifest revolves around this code:

```
exec { "add-apt-repository-${name}":
    environment  => $proxy_env,
    command      => "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository ${options} ${name}",
    unless       => "/usr/bin/test -s ${sources_list_d}/${sources_list_d_filename}",
    user         => 'root',
    logoutput    => 'on_failure',
    notify       => Exec['apt_update'],
    require      => [
    File['sources.list.d'],
    Package[$package],
    ],
}
```

By setting this event to `notify => Exec['apt_update']` once this exec has fired it will send a refresh to the `apt_update` exec resource, thus triggering an `apt-get update`. The reason why this does not happen every puppet run is because this attribute prevents the command from being executed if the repository was already previously added:

```
    unless       => "/usr/bin/test -s ${sources_list_d}/${sources_list_d_filename}",
```

Hope this helps.

Good luck!